# Where to declare variable global in a for loop?

Tags: python

Where am I supposed to write `global users`? Doesn't matter where I put it, it always doesn't change its value .

```
import os.path

check = os.path.isfile("users.txt")
users = {"tuna":"fish"}
def check():
    global users
    if check == True :
        with open("users.txt" , "r") as f:
            for line in f:
                (key, val) = line.split()
                users[key] = val

    elif check == False :
        with open("users.txt" , "a+") as f:
            f.write("root root")
            for line in f:
                (key, val) = line.split()
                users[key] = val

check()
print(users) #it just shows {tuna fish} instead of the new things
```

Comment: You're trying to use the `check` name for two different things in the same scope at the same time. Pick two names.

Comment: because... your `users.txt` is empty? Can you give us the content in `users.txt`?

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica That's a problem but not the cause here, since you still call `check()` before the variable name is overwritten

Comment: @GarethMa: I'm not sure what you're trying to say. The `check` name is rebound as soon as the function is defined.

Comment: nvm my bad, I didn't get what you meant

Comment: You got a variable named `check` and a function named `check()` and it's messing things up. Give one of them a different name.

Comment: @user2357112 thanks this solved the problem , i can't believe i didn't notice that

Comment: @Gareth Ma no it's not , the problem is solved but thanks for trying to help

Comment: @martineau this solved the problem , thank you

Comment: user12179645: That good to hear. For the record, @user2357112 supports Monica actually mentioned it first. However I still wonder if you really understand what was going on…

Comment: @martineau what do you mean ? + i actually replied to ;user2357112 supports Monica;

Comment: I meant simply that @user2357112supportsMonica pointed out that you were using `check` for two different things before I did.

Comment: Use different names for variable and method names.